# upper bound for quadratic form in terms of vector norm and eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, quadratic-forms, upper-lower-bounds

I have a quadratic form. if Q, P and M are positive and symmetric matrices.

$$(-x^T Q x - 2 x^T Q e - e^T Q e) + (y^T M y + 2 x^T P y + 2 e^T P y )$$

how can I get an upper bound for this quadratic form in terms of vector norm and eigenvalues?

Comment: Gotta close those latex expressions with another $$

Comment: Also, what's e? A unit vector?  PSD gives you the property that $x'Px \ge 0$ for all $x$, but it says nothing (that I know about, at least) about $x'Py$.  I think of all the intuition of properties of PSD matrices as coming from $x'Px = x'A'DAx=y'Dy = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 \lambda_i$ where each $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of the diagonalization.

Comment: What have you tried? What approach do you like - differentiation or diagonalisation?